# Program counter changes oddly without any instruction modifying it (qemu-arm, bare metal)

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, gdb, arm, qemu

I'm currently trying to make a program i wrote run on a bare metal arm device. Since i'm not having the device (yet), i try to run the code on an arm emulation using qemu.

i run my code with this command: `qemu-system-arm -M realview-pb-a8 -m 128M -nographic -s -S -kernel myprog`.

The execution gets stuck at always the same point, even if i use other board setups. This is the place it gets stuck (some piece of openSSL code):

```
   0x398b4 <EVP_CipherInit_ex+884>         ldr    r3, [r11, #-24]
   0x398b8 <EVP_CipherInit_ex+888>         ldr    r3, [r3]
   0x398bc <EVP_CipherInit_ex+892>         ldr    r12, [r3, #20]
   0x398c0 <EVP_CipherInit_ex+896>         ldr    r0, [r11, #-24]
   0x398c4 <EVP_CipherInit_ex+900>         ldr    r1, [r11, #-36] ; 0x24  
   0x398c8 <EVP_CipherInit_ex+904>         ldr    r2, [r11, #4] 
   0x398cc <EVP_CipherInit_ex+908>         ldr    r3, [r11, #8]
   0x398d0 <EVP_CipherInit_ex+912>         mov    lr, pc
   0x398d4 <EVP_CipherInit_ex+916>         bx     r12
[..]
-> 0x391e4 <aes_init_key>          push   {r11, lr}  <- Strange thing happens at this instruction.
   0x391e8 <aes_init_key+4>        add    r11, sp, #4
   0x391ec <aes_init_key+8>        sub    sp, sp, #40     ; 0x28
   0x391f0 <aes_init_key+12>       str    r0, [r11, #-24]
   0x391f4 <aes_init_key+16>       str    r1, [r11, #-28]
```

Right after the instruction at 0x391e4 the $pc changes to 0x391e6 instead of 0x391e8. This is not a valid address, so it jumps right to the beginning of the file at execution. If i change the $pc to the correct value in debugger i reach 0x391e8 but the $pc is again set to a wrong value (0x391ea). I was not able to reproduce this behaviour with other code than mine.

Here is a dump of the main registers right before shit happens.

```
r0   0xe28db004 -494030844    r1   0x7aeb8  503480
r2      0x7aea8     503464    r3       0x1       1
r4      0x7df98     515992    r5   0x7dfa8  516008
r6          0x0          0    r7       0x0       0
r8          0x0          0    r9       0x0      0
r10     0x60000     393216    r11  0x7ae34  503348
r12     0x391e5     233957    sp   0x7ae08  0x7ae08 <__malloc_av_+252>
lr      0x398d8     235736    pc   0x391e6  0x391e6 <aes_init_key+2>
cpsr 0x200001f3  536871411
```

And here one right after:

```
r0   0xe28db004  -494030844   r1     0x7aeb8    503480
r2      0x7aea8      503464   r3         0x1         1
r4      0x7df98      515992   r5     0x7dfa8    516008
r6          0x0           0   r7         0x0         0
r8          0x0           0   r9         0x0         0 
r10     0x60000      393216   r11    0x7ae34    503348
r12     0x391e5      233957   sp     0x7e000   0x7e000
lr      0x391e8      233960   pc         0x8       0x8
cpsr 0x200001db   536871387
```

How can i resolve this issue? Could this be a compiler error?

I tried these compiler flags: `-marm` `-mthumb-interwork`

Comment: [`bx r12`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473k/dom1361289866466.html), and r12 has the lsb set - the only thing "behaving oddly" here is apparently your compiler/linker, to somehow have a Thumb symbol for what looks to be a piece of ARM code.

Comment: What is a thumb symbol?

Comment: As in, the lsb of the address of a [symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table) in the object file is used to indicate whether that function is Thumb code or ARM code. Does compiling and linking everything with the `-marm` option make any difference?

Comment: I will check that on monday.

Comment: It doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2 byte change sounds suspiciously like thumb mode and indeed your `cpsr` bit #5 is set. Either this is indeed thumb code, in which case you are disassembling it wrong, or it is arm code in which case it is called wrongfully in thumb mode.